Rewrite URL for all API operations in Azure API management service
I have a web api with paths as:
<WebApiHost>/api/v1/operation1
<WebApiHost>/api/v1/operation2
<WebApiHost>/api/v1/operation3

In my Azure API management service, I want the front end to be:
<ApiManagementHost>/api-name/v1/operation1
<ApiManagementHost>/api-name/v1/operation2
<ApiManagementHost>/api-name/v1/operation3

What is the best way to achieve this?
I have tried to achieve this by creating the API in API Management by importing an Open API spec file, and setting the API suffix to "api-name" as well as using a version identifier in the path as "v1", then gone through each of the operations front-ends and removing the "/api/v1/" sections of the paths that came from the open API definition. Then I have tried adding an inbound policy that applies to all operations such as:
<inbound>
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.StartsWith("/test/pmi-quotes/v1/"))">
            <rewrite-uri template="/api/v1/@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Replace(&quot;/test/pmi-quotes/v1/&quot;, &quot;&quot;))" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <rewrite-uri template="/api/@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path)" />
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
    <base />
</inbound>

With the idea being that requests as "/api-name/v1/{operation-path}" get re-written as "/api/v1/{operation-path}"
But this returns a 404. Looking at the trace it seems like the re-write rule isn't resolving as the URL contains the expression:
forward-request (0.108 ms)
{
    "message": "Request is being forwarded to the backend service. Timeout set to 300 seconds",
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "<WebApiHost>/api/v1/@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Replace(\"/api-name/v1/\", \"\"))",
        "headers": [


Step 1: Create an API with API URL Suffix = api-name and Web service URL = <WebApiHost>/api

Step 2: In this API, create an Operation with URL = /*

That's it, no additional policies are required.
<ApiManagementHost>/api-name/v1/operation1 will be redirected to <WebApiHost>/api/v1/operation1, and so on.
Update: If you want to create separate operations, use the following URLs in Step 2:

/v1/operation1
/v1/operation2
/v1/operation3
etc.


Still, no additional policies are required.

Hmm I get how this might work, but then when I go to the developer portal surely there won't be any routes defined in the spec generated? I.e. I want to be able to see /api-name/v1/opertation1 etc

@DavidMasters I updated my answer after your comment, hope it helps
